# Запретить редактирование JTable

Tags: java, swing

Нужно запретить редактирование JTable, чтобы при нажатие на конкретную строку она только выделялась и можно было обработать слушателем это нажатие

Comment: setFocusable(false);
setClickable(true);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

При создании модели таблицы, переопределите метод isCellEditable

```
    TableModel tableModel = new DefaultTableModel(){
        @Override
        public boolean isCellEditable(int i, int i1) {
            return false;
        }
    };
```